# How to update all rows in particular column of pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I want to read a csv file and store this file in pandas data-frame, after that I want to check one column value is equal to constant variable and that equal rows should be kept in separate data-frame.

Next step is to update one column from the separate data-frame. In this step I'm iterating through whole data-frame and updating all the rows of particular column, so it will take too much time because my data-frame is has thousands of rows.

**Input.csv-**

```
line_no,time
205,1467099122677889
205,1467099122677889
206,1467099363719028
207,1467099363818373
207,1467099363918360
208,1467099363818373
210,1467099363958749
```

**Program-**

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":

   file_path = 'Input.csv'
   input_line_no = 205

   pd_dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path,delimiter=',',keep_default_na=False)
   match_df = pd.DataFrame(pd_dataframe.loc[pd_dataframe['line_no'] == int(input_line_no)])

   if match_df.empty:
       print 'Given line no is not present in dataframe.'
       sys.exit(1)
   match_df = match_df.applymap(str)
   for index in range(0,len(match_df.index)):

        epoch_time = match_df.iloc[index]['time']
        stamp = int(str(epoch_time)+'0')
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp / 10000000.0).strftime('%H:%M:%S %f')[:-3]
        match_df['time'].apply(str)
        match_df.iloc[index]['time'] = date

   print match_df.to_csv(index=False)
```

This time column is in epoch time I want to convert it into the human readable timestamp so logic is for that purpose only.

But I'm facing execution time issue regarding to this task. Is 
there any other way to update the existing data-frame's column in the faster manner?

Comment: If use `date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp / 10000000.0)` it return `2434-11-27 04:20:26.778889`. Is it right? Or is it `2016-06-28 07:32:02` ?

Comment: @jezrael - yes it is correct and  don't worry about that. I just want to know how can I reduce execution time of this updating column of data-frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can use first:

```
match_df = pd_dataframe[pd_dataframe['line_no'] == int(input_line_no)].copy()
print (match_df)
   line_no              time
0      205  1467099122677889
1      205  1467099122677889
```

You can use `apply`, because [timestamp limitations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

> In [55]: pd.Timestamp.max
>   Out[55]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')

```
match_df['time'] = match_df.time
                           .apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(x)+'0')
                                   / 10000000.0)) 
print (match_df)
   line_no                       time
0      205 2016-06-28 09:32:02.677889
1      205 2016-06-28 09:32:02.677889
```

And then:

```
match_df['time'] = match_df.time
                           .apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(x)+'0') 
                                   / 10000000.0).strftime('%H:%M:%S %f')[:-3]) 
print (match_df)
   line_no          time
0      205  09:32:02 677
1      205  09:32:02 677
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure with converting epoch_time to datetime. Is my output correct?

Comment: @jezrael- Is this script is inserting correct row's time to it's correct position? because in csv file all time's are not same so it is necessary to change particular row's time into human readable time-stamp and place at that position only?

Comment: for converting epoch into human readable time-stamp my logic is good because of some requirements so, can I place my logic for converting to human time-stamp in your code? if yes then how?

Comment: I am looking for solution, give me a time.

Comment: @jezrael- This one is sufficient and correct also.  match_df['time'] = match_df.time.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(x)+'0') / 10000000.0).strftime('%H:%M:%S %f')[:-3])

Comment: Edit your answer. It is helpful for others also and Thanks for giving me a direction towards my goal.

Comment: Yes, but I think it is not neccessary - first add one `0` and  then remove it by divide by 10 - or i something missing?

Comment: And in original you add twice `0` and then divide by `10000000`, so i try remove 2 zerous and divide only by `100000`. But if `10000000` is some constant, then add `0` is necessary.

Comment: you didn't miss anything, just you don't know the epoch here which does not have last zero, so we must have to create it as 17 digit by appending '0' for producing correct milliseconds result.

Comment: @jezrael- yes that was my mistake, only one zero is necessary.